# JSON-RPC with apiblueprint

Tags: apiblueprint

Apiary provides a clean interface for declaring URI parameters allowing for easy experimentation via thier console with a nice fill in the blank interface.

Is this possible to do for json-rpc or any http body parameter? If not, this would be incredibly useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible yet, but it will be soon via [message body description](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/25).

However, this is for arbitrary body parameters. I am not sure JSON-RPC is going to work well for API blueprint as it is modelled more around resources; as RPC "overloads" a single resource, the result is probably not going to look very nice.

Comment: I'm considering using API Blueprint for documenting an JSON-RPC API. Based on this Q&A it's not recommended. Is it still not recommended..?

Comment: The message body description is there (via MSON), but haven't really tried JSON-RPC with it. I think you'll still have problems with resulting documentation being confusing.  You may give it a shot though, let us know how it went!